# How to reference NFT image descriptors correctly in github pages repository?

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I'm trying to import the AR.js NFT example into my own repository hosted with Github Pages. I've generated image descriptors for a new image and imported into a folder named public/assets/.

When the website loads, it shows the camera image, and the loading text, but on the console the following error appears: Error in loading marker on Worker 404

My image descriptors are referenced in this way:

```
url="public/assets/Marker2"
```

Comment: It seems like a server configuration issue. Without runnable code it will be hard to help you further. [Glitch is a good option](https://glitch.com/~aframe)

Comment: it is a duplicated question see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262063/image-tracking-and-location-based-ar-with-a-frame-and-ar-js-3-having-a-problem-w/61349001#61349001