# NFT Image tracking works locally but not on server (404 onError)

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, ar.js

I'm new to AR.js and I've been trying to run using the NFT marker with Three.js and a custom image to pop a model. It works well in localhost but when I upload on my github page there is a 404 "onError" from the ar-nft.js. I tried change the link the ar-nft to https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/three.js/build/ar-nft.js but still gives the error. I assume the descriptors URL can't find the data nft files on server. If so, I'm not sure how do I link it.

The whole project is in https://github.com/pillipillow/ARjs-with-Threejs

Code below is from https://github.com/pillipillow/ARjs-with-Threejs/blob/main/nft-tracking.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Viewport</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src = "libs/threeJS/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/three.js/build/ar-nft.js"></script>
    <script>THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL = "libs/arJS/"</script>

    <script type= "module">
        import { GLTFLoader } from './libs/jsm/GLTFLoader.js';
        
        var scene, camera, renderer, clock;

        var arToolkitSource, arToolkitContext;

        var markerRoot;

        var model;

        init();
        update();

        function init()
        {
            // Scene
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // Camera
            camera = new THREE.Camera();
            scene.add(camera);

            // Renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true,
                alpha: true,
            });
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color('lightgrey'), 0)
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            renderer.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            renderer.domElement.style.left = '0px';
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            clock = new THREE.Clock();

            // ArToolkitSource
            arToolkitSource = new THREEx.ArToolkitSource({
                sourceType : 'webcam',
                sourceWidth: 1280,
                sourceHeight: 720,
                displayWidth : 1280,
                displayHeight: 720
            })

            function onResize(){
                arToolkitSource.onResizeElement()
                arToolkitSource.copyElementSizeTo(renderer.domElement)
                if( arToolkitContext.arController !== null ){
                    arToolkitSource.copyElementSizeTo(arToolkitContext.arController.canvas)
                }
            }

            arToolkitSource.init(function onReady(){
                // use a resize to fullscreen mobile devices
                setTimeout(function() {
                    onResize();
                }, 1000);
            })

            // handle resize
            window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
                onResize();
            })

            window.addEventListener('arjs-nft-loaded', function(ev){
                console.log(ev);
            })

            // ArToolkitContext
            arToolkitContext = new THREEx.ArToolkitContext({
                cameraParametersUrl: "libs/arJS/data/camera_para.dat",
                detectionMode: "color",
            });

            // copy projection matrix to camera when initialization complete
            arToolkitContext.init( function onCompleted(){
                camera.projectionMatrix.copy( arToolkitContext.getProjectionMatrix() );
            });

            // Ar Marker
            markerRoot = new THREE.Group();
            scene.add(markerRoot);

            var markerControls = new THREEx.ArMarkerControls(arToolkitContext, markerRoot, {
                type: "nft",
                descriptorsUrl: "assets/dataNFT/coloring3d-bear-small",
                smooth: true,
                smoothCount : 10,
                smoothTolerance : 0.01,
                smoothThreshold : 5
            })

            var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("assets/images/bird-render.png");
            var alphaTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load("assets/images/bird-alpha.png")
            texture.flipY = false;
            alphaTexture.flipY = false;
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map : texture, 
                    alphaMap : alphaTexture,
                    alphaTest : 0.5,
                    transparent : false,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide});

            var videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(arToolkitSource.domElement);
            videoTexture.flipY = false;
            var videoMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map : videoTexture});
           
            // Place the model
            const loader = new GLTFLoader();

            loader.load(
                "assets/models/bird.glb",
                function(gltf)
                {
                    model = gltf.scene.children[0];
                    model.name = "Bird";
                    model.scale.set(30,30,30);
                    model.position.set(130,130,-130);
                    model.traverse((o) => {
                        if (o.isMesh) o.material = material;
                        });
                    markerRoot.add(model);
                },
                    // called while loading is progressing
                function ( xhr ) 
                {
                    console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
                },

                // called when loading has errors
                function ( error ) 
                {
                    console.log( 'An error happened' );
                }
            )

            /*var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30,30,30);
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color : 0xFF0000});
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            mesh.position.set(150,150,-150);
            markerRoot.add(mesh);*/
        }

        function update()
        {
            requestAnimationFrame(update);

            if(markerRoot.visible)
            {
                //model.rotation.z += 0.01;
            }


            // update artoolkit on every frame
            if ( arToolkitSource.ready !== false )
            {
                arToolkitContext.update( arToolkitSource.domElement );
            }
                
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [NFT-Marker-Creator](https://ar-js-org.github.io/NFT-Marker-Creator/). Setup might look like this:

```
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js">
</script>

<style>
  .arjs-loader {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .arjs-loader div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
```

And there's always [official documentation](https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/image-tracking/).

Comment: so do I need to create the marker again even though it works locally? and the code above is just the style for the loader in aframe is it not? I'm using three.js.

Comment: Leave a marker as is, and touching a style – it's just an example.

Comment: The typical trigger for an error 404 message is when website content has been removed or moved to another URL. There are also other reasons why an error message could appear. ... The URL or its content (such as files or images) was either deleted or moved.

Comment: That is the issue I'm dealing with as I have explained in my question. I know that the nft descriptors URL link are at fault but I just don't know what's the right url to put in descriptors when I upload the files into the github repository as a page, hence why I also included my github page for other progammers to help me out.

Comment: Hi @pillipillow this is a gh-pages issue read my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262063/image-tracking-and-location-based-ar-with-a-frame-and-ar-js-3-having-a-problem-w/61349001#61349001,  section Hosting on a WebServer (Github pages)